# jQuery Strange duplicate iteration

Tags: jquery, forms, webforms

I have a form with 5 file upload fields and a '[+] Add more file' link. It works fine by displaying one field per click, but after I an attachment the DOM structure changes as can be seen below and therefore when I hit [+] Add more files, it displays me twice fields at once (instead one). I don't clearly understand why

[image]

Here is the HTML structure
[image]

Here is jQuery code:

```
//FETCH THE ARRAY OF 5    
var webform_divs = $('.webform-client-form').find('div[id$="-ajax-wrapper"]');
//INITIAL STATE    
    if (!($("#addmore").length > 0)) {
                    webform_divs.hide();
                   webform_divs.first().show();
                    webform_divs.last().after('<a id="addmore" href=#>'+"[+] Add more files"+'</a>');
                }
//FUNCTION CALL 
more_upload_fields(webform_divs);    

//FUNCTION BODY
                function more_upload_fields(field_wrappers) {

                    $("#addmore").click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        field_wrappers.each(function(index) {
                           if ($(this).is(":hidden")) {
                                //console.log(index);
                                //console.log($(this));
                                $(this).show();
                                if ($(this).next().is('#addmore')) {
                                    $("#addmore").hide();
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Maybe someone help me remove the <div style='display:block'></div> wrapping.

Comment: you need not have 5 fileupload boxes created already in dom. you can create them on the fly and check the count (for limit to 5) and stop him adding more files. Simple.

Comment: This is not possible due to the fact that I am using Drupal and this way the attachments are not added to the session.

Comment: please create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem.